# Jenkins: how to block a job to make it unrunnable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

This is not just another question about concurrent job execution in Jenkins. The problem I have is that there are several jobs that run independently from one another. When they finish it should be possible to run a manual job. The condition though is that all those automated jobs should be in successful state. Otherwise it should not be possible to run this manual job. It should also not be possible to run or even schedule run of this manual job if those other jobs are running.

I searched for the answer everywhere and checked every possible plugin that serves synchronization. But I did not figure it out how to solve the above problem.

Comment: Maybe absolute overkill - but did you try the pipeline plug-in?

Comment: @mylenereiners If a pipline plug-in has an ability to do what I need please describe it thoroughly in an answer. There is a bounty to win and I cannot accept comments.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the delivery pipeline plugin (see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin for the download and http://www.infoq.com/articles/orch-pipelines-jenkins for a thorough description) could do what you want.

You can run a lot of jobs (in parallel or not), and when (and only when) they succeed another job (or more). You even can add manual steps (needing a button click when your pipeline may continue).
Everything is configurable - and quite stable at this moment.

No-one should be able to manually (or otherwise) start a job that is in "waiting state" for other jobs to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this question:
*Otherwise it should not be possible to run this manual job. It should also not be possible to run or even schedule run of this manual job if those other jobs are running.*

You can use [the Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin) and create a category which will include your automated jobs and the manual jobs.

If one automated job is running, it will be impossible to launch the manual jobs.

Regarding your first question, did you have a look to the [Join plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin)?

Cheers

Comment: I know about throttling mechanisms and many ways of doing this in Jenkins. What I am asking about is not only I want to block the ability to execute this manual job when the others are running. I want to make it unrunnable and unschedulable if one of those previous jobs will fail. With Join plugin I can run a single job after completion of previous group of automated jobs. This plugin cannot be used to block execution of manual job.

Comment: One solution should be to generate some "status" file from the previous jobs.

Next the manual job can scan these files when starting.

If one of the previous status is not OK, the job stops.

If all the previous status are OK, then the manual job should delete all the "status" files.

It's not very clean, but it should work...

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin can also be option. Setup promotions in that way that manual approval is needed and build will not fail only if automated jobs are done.